# Python mechanize click submit on multi submit form

Tags: python, mechanize

I have to click on the first submit on a multi submit form. The submit code is as below:

```
        <div class="grid ">
            <div class="grid__item grid-u-2-10">
                <label class="form__label">Auto-Fill:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="grid__item grid-u-8-10" id="autofill-button-container">
                <input type="button" id="autofill" name="autofill" value="Auto-Fill" class="form__input" onclick="AutoFill();"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;Use AutoFill first, as it will replace everything below.
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried:

```
br.open(url+"upload.php")

br.select_form(nr=7)
r = br.submit(label='Auto-Fill')
```

however it returns:

```
mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching kind 'clickable', label 'Auto-Fill'
```

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to click the wrong button.  The input-button action is what you need to go for.  Assuming you're selecting the right form.  If not br.select_form(nr=8)

Try:

```
br.submit(name=autofill)
```